# Unsupported 16 bit application

Tags: c, exe, lcc

I just downloaded and installed the lcc64 compiler.
To test if it works, i compiled this program

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {      
    printf("test");
return 0;
}
```

by using `lcc64.exe Source.c -o prog.exe`.
But if i try to start the program `prog.exe` in console,
a window pops up saying "Unsupported 16 bit application", "The Program or feature '\??\C:\lcc\lcc\bin\prog.exe' cant be opened due to an incompatibility with 64-bit versions of Windows."

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: The man page of lcc says: "lcc is a cross compiler; -Wf-target=target/os causes lcc to generate code for target running the operating system denoted by os." You could try to add `-Wf-target=x86/win32`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I strongly recommend that you download and use the [user manual](http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~lcc-win32/) for lcc that is available on the project page.

The problem here is that the compiler does not produce executable files - it produces object files.  You need to then use the linker to produce the executable file.  You've overridden the standard output of the compiler to name the `.obj` file it produces `prog.exe`, but naming an `.obj` file an `.exe` file does not make it an executable.  To get your test to work, in the simplest way, you need to:

```
 ..\test> lcc64 source.c
```

this produces a file `source.obj`.  You then need to

```
 ..\test> lcclnk64 source.obj
```

this produces a file `source.exe`.  Running the file then produces output :

```
 ..\test> source
 test
```

For a larger project you would typically be writing and maintaining a build script that manages the correct order of compilation and linking for all of the sources into the final executable.

Comment: It works :), thank you. I used tcc before so i assumed it would work the same way.